# Material using plain colours getting burnt when using THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping

Tags: colors, three.js, gltf

We are updating our three.js app setup so that it uses the `THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping` (because our scene uses IBL from an EXR environment map).

In that process, materials using textures are now looking great (map colours used to be washed out before the change as illustrated below).

with `renderer.toneMapping = THREE.LinearToneMapping` (default)
[image]

with `renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping`
[image]

However, the problem is that plain colours (without any maps) are now looking burnt...

with `renderer.toneMapping = THREE.LinearToneMapping` (default)
[image]

with `renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping`
[image]

It's now totally impossible to get bright yellow or green for example. Turning down the `renderer.toneMappingExposure` or the `material.envMapIntensity` can help, but materials with textures then get way too dark... Ie. provided any given parameter, material using plain colours are either too bright, or material using textures are too dark.

I'm not sure if I am missing something, but this looks like there would be an issue in this setup. Would there be any other parameter that we are overlooking that is causing this result?

Otherwise, we are loading all our models using the `GLTFLoader`, and we have `renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;` as per the documentation of the `GLTFLoader`.
Our environment map is an equirectangular EXR loaded with `EXRLoader`:

```js
import { EXRLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/EXRLoader';

const envMapLoader = new EXRLoader();
envMapLoader.load(
  environmentMapUrl,
  rawTexture => {
    const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
    pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();
    const envMapTarget = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(rawTexture);
    const { texture } = envMapTarget;
    return texture;
  },
  ...
)
```

Comment: Tonemapping changes the colors of your materials, that's expected. If you need solid colors to remain unchanged, you will need to avoid tonemapping them. See https://discourse.threejs.org/t/acesfilmictonemapping-leading-to-low-contrast-textures/15484.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) As far as I now understand, this is a necessity to be able to fit more colours into the LDR, and the best workaround is to check if a material is using a `map` or not, and set `material.toneMapped` to `false` if it doesn't?

Comment: Hm, no I would not recommend that workaround. Why are you using tonemapping, if you don't want [color] tones to be mapped? Using IBL does not require tonemapping, and whether the material uses textures or not isn't important. Tonemapping creates space in the LDR gamut for more _lighting_ variation (note the very "flat" shading on your 3rd image) by shifting original colors in certain ways. You'll need to choose colors that give the final result you want, choose another tonemapping method, or disable tonemapping. The three.js forum may be more helpful for this topic.

Comment: I got the tip to use `ACESFilmicToneMapping` from WestLangley a long time ago because our envMap is HDR (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/18569#issuecomment-584383805), and not tone mapping yielded a washed out scene, specifically for textures (which is correct and visible from my first and second image). The problem is now that when using that tone mapping, it seems impossible to achieve vibrant solid colors by using the base `color` parameter alone of our `MeshStandardMaterial`s, or at least that is what I can't seem to achieve, and that feels like a shortcoming to me?

Comment: You may need to go to the three.js forums for this question. There is no quick fix to add HDR lighting to colors that are already 100% saturated. Lighting is not a simple topic, and different tonemapping methods make different tradeoffs here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all the pointers and help. I think I at least understand a lot better the underlying reasons/causes for our situation.

Comment: @Silvain would you say this question is answered? I think it's appropriate to answer your own question since no one else did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that this is expected behaviour and there will always be tradeoffs in lightning/colors. One has thus to empirically select settings depending on the specific setup/application and desired results.

From [Don McCurdy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267940/material-using-plain-colours-getting-burnt-when-using-three-acesfilmictonemappin?noredirect=1#comment112042245_63267940) directly on my question above:

> You may need to go to the three.js forums for this question. There is no quick fix to add HDR lighting to colors that are already
> 100% saturated. Lighting is not a simple topic, and different
> tonemapping methods make different tradeoffs here.